# Need help on CvSVM

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, svm

I couldnt find proper references about how to pass the SVM parameters to the opencv cvSvm class. I got the parameter list, but not any tutorial on how to convert the parameters to the CV data structures.

Can I have some help please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Construct a `CvSVMParams` object.

Its members are:

- `svm_type`: SVM algorithm to use
- `kernel_type`: SVM kernel form
- `degree`: Degree for polynomial kernel
- `gamma`: Scale for polynomial, RBF or sigmoid kernel
- `coef0`: Offset for polynomial or sigmoid kernel
- `C`: C ratio for selecting support vectors
- `nu`: nu value for nu-SVR algorithm
- `p`: p value for eps-SVR
- `class_weights`: Class weights for C-SVM
- `term_crit`: Termination criteria in `CvTermCriteria`

Change appropriate fields and pass it to `CvSVM` constructor. An SVM will be trained with your parameters.

```
CvSVMParams params ;
params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC ;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF ;
params.gamma = 0.5 ;
CvSVM svm(&samples, &labels, 0, 0, params) ;
```

See documentation of CvSVM for more information:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/support_vector_machines.html